# Display alternate backup site when main goes offline

Tags: backup, web-server, iis-7

We currently host our website in-house. Consistently we're loosing internet or power. I'd like to house a secondary site at that would be used when our main is offline.

**How would I go about displaying a backup site when our main goes offline using IIS7?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would require having your DNS hosted outside the company at a DNS provider.  Then when the office network goes offline your change the DNS to point to the hosting companies IP address.  If you are having this many problems, why not just host the site outside normally?

Comment: plus 1 for hosting the website in a properly powered and connected facility

Comment: It's funny I had actually said "don't bother asking" in the post but removed it. We have a extensive DB that we cannot open up to the world. It's easier if we host internally instead of allowing access externally. Not my policy.

Comment: As I said, this can be done.  You'll need a DNS hosting company that gives you an API to change the DNS on the fly and set a low TTL. You'll need a machine to monitor your main site and if it goes away changes the DNS to point your sites to the backup site.